# Will Inverse Mode become available?

Tags: 18.04

*Coming form 12.04 to 18.04 I was supprized not to find the Inverse Mode anymore. As I have "very poor eysight" I need this fucntion to work on Ubuntu, otherwise I have to switch back to Windows :-((
Will this function be available again soon?

in the meantime I use XCALIB but this inverses also pictures and video :-( *

Comment: You mean "high contrast"? Then open Settings application and go to "Universal Access". You should be able to turn on "High Contrast" from there.

Comment: @pomsky I think the poster wants a dark GUI and dark application body with light text wherever possible. Images and videos should retain their original appearance.

Comment: If MS Windows does what you need, switching back is the easiest. If you want to stay on Linux, maybe there are other distros that offer what you need. I'm not aware of any. If you don't mind doing a bit of work, you can start off with a dark wallpaper for your desktop. Some applications come with dark themes. Others allow you to customize them to suit your visual needs. Yet others, like browsers, allow you to customize web pages to make them have dark dark backgrounds and light text. YouTube has a dark mode.

Comment: its exactly what Pomsky says and this function was available in earlier versions (fi 10.04, 12.04) I don't see why this it not possible anymore? Everyone with poor eyesight need.

Comment: Problem closed without a reason why this function is not available anymore? :-((